# Using multiple Ports/Hosts with Traefik and Docker Container

Tags: docker, docker-compose, plesk, traefik

How can I run a Docker Container with Traefik as a reverse proxy that can be accessed with different domains.

For example when I visit *frontend.com* traefik redirects the request to Port 123 but if I visit *backend.com* it redirects the request to Port 456 of the container.

Below you can see my current configuration. When i visit *plesk.filser-webdesign.de* the correct backend is shown so it seems to work but when I visit wiki.filser-webdesign.de a 404 error is displayed.

```
version: '3.5'

networks:
    traefik:
      name: traefik

services:
  plesk:
    image: plesk/plesk
    restart: always
    container_name: plesk
#    volumes:
#      - ./data:/var
#    ports:
#      - 8447:8447
#      - 8880:8880
    labels:
      - traefik.enable=true
      - traefik.frontend.passHostHeader=true

      - traefik.pleskback.backend=plesk-backend
      - traefik.pleskback.frontend.rule=Host:plesk.filser-webdesign.de
      - traefik.pleskback.port=8880
      - traefik.pleskback.protocol=http

      - traefik.pleskfront.backend=plesk-frontend
      - traefik.pleskfront.frontend.fule=Host:wiki.filser-webdesign.de
#      - traefik.pleskfront.frontend.priority=1
      - traefik.pleskfront.port=80
      - traefik.pleskfront.protocol=http
    networks:
      - traefik
```

Comment: The [traefik forums](https://community.containo.us/c/traefik/traefik-v2/10) may be a better place to ask for help.

Answer (score 0):

Check the first line in the frontEnd. I think you wanted to write:

```
- traefik.pleskfront.frontend=plesk-frontend
```

Bye.